# Using Global variable in Cucumber step

Tags: cucumber

I have a cucumber test checking a text like ABCD@USERNAME.website. And USERNAME can be gathered from a global variable called USER.

My step is :

```
And I check the file contains "ABCD@USERNAME.website".
```

I am using this step to any kind of checks in file. How can i parameterise the USERNAME in this step?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: If you're asking how to make parameters for steps within the feature file global, then you are working at too low a level with your tests.

Your test should be a constant. Keep user details in a separate place, and reference the email like: `And I check that the file contains John Smith's email address` or something similar. Check the JSON/Map/Object for the key of John Smith and grab his email address.

Comment: I am trying to cover a corner case by re-using the current step def. This corner case can use an already defined global variable. But i think this is not how it is meant to be. I just wondered about the possibility.

Comment: How to share this variable/object between steps would depend on the programming language you're using. Please provide that information.

Comment: I am using ruby

Comment: I created another step as i should do